# long parameter to PartialView in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I'm trying to call a partial view with a long as model:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Galaxies.Gal.Views.GalaxyPartial, Model.Id)
```

where Model.Id is a long.

In the called partial, I've:

```
@model long

@Html.Action(MVC.Galaxies.Common.GalAction(Model))
```

but I've a compiler error:

> CS1061: 'GalaxiesController.ViewsClass' does not contain a definition
>   for 'GalaxyPartial' and no extension method 'GalaxyPartial' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'GalaxiesController.ViewsClass' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I achieve this ? I don't want to pass a whole model to the partial but only the id.

Comment: What error? And why not pass the model?

Comment: I don't need to pass a whole model, I just need to pass an Id.

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: But what difference do you think that makes? (it makes none at all). And you still have not stated your error

Comment: answer edited with the compiler error

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/partialViewName.cshtml", Model.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with type of the ID. The problem is that partial [expects a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx) that is a view name as an input, and you try to give it some type that does not even exist, it seems.

Assuming the view is called `GalaxyPartial`, this is what should be done:

```
@Html.Partial("GalaxyPartial", Model.Id)
```

Comment: @andreasperelli. I see. You mean it is supposed to return a string, because error obviously points out that `MVC.Galaxies.Gal.Views.GalaxyPartial` does not even exist. Are you sure you got it entirely correct? And the visibility of the property is sufficient?

Comment: some issues with Visual Studio... restarting it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio solved the issue...